# Enigmatic Movie Riddle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

Here is a little Enigma Test! Find which movie name is hidden down there!

> First thiNg yOu do Is you sprinT towArds dowN
>   Invent a triad and run towards rIght and get last septuplets.
>   Now this Stanza Will End the Game of Movies Combat when you go up and west to get a ▭!

**A snap of the above, to clarify what the final symbol is meant to look like:**

[image]

Comment: Combat when you go up and west to get a what? It's just a box for me.

Comment: Is that character at the end supposed to be just a square, or should I be seeing an emoji or something?

Comment: @randal'thor- It's a shape. I'm afraid revealing the shape might serve as a hint. :) But for now, its a shape.

Comment: No idea if it helps, but it's [UTF-8 #9645](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)

Comment: OK, so you're seeing the same as me. That's a relief.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've got most of this, but am having trouble putting together the middle section.

*First thiNg yOu do Is you sprinT towArds dowN*

> We read downwards starting from the beginning of the riddle to get the first part of the movie title: **FIN**.

*Invent a triad and run towards rIght and get last septuplets.*

> Running towards the right means going rightwards within the text of the riddle, starting from the point we've reached so far (the beginning of the third line). The capital letters within the third line give SWEGMC, which isn't very helpful, but then we "run towards right" *within each word" and pick the final letter to get **ALDEST**.

(I was a little confused about the meaning of "triad" and "septuplet" here, since we don't actually use either of the numbers 3 or 7 in the solution of this line, but the OP [explained it to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33945127#33945127) in chat.)

*Now this Stanza Will End the Game of Movies Combat when you go up and west to get a ▭!*

> From wherever we've now ended up (probably the end of the third line), we go up and then left (west), so as to form a rectangle (▭) within the letters of the riddle. So we pass up through the right-hand side of the second line and then leftwards along the top line to get back to the beginning; reading capital letters only, this gives **INATION**.

So the rectangle is

> `F N O I T A N`
>  `I           I`
>  `N A L D E S T`

and the movie title is

> FIN-ALDEST-INATION or **[*Final Destination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination).**

Comment: Going good. Try harder and you shall pass the test! :) +1